# Read batch job params and add custom tags to built-in Spring Batch metrics

Tags: spring, spring-batch, metrics, micrometer

I would like to add custom tags to Spring Batch's built-in metrics.

For example, out of the box Spring Batch comes with this:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/monitoring-and-metrics.html

The metrics are automatically gathered and posted with a `spring.batch.*` naming convention. There are also some built-in tags associated with each type of metric.

Is it possible to add custom tags to these?

I understand a `MeterFilter` will allow me to modify the metrics and add tags, but I'm not sure it gets me access to the job parameters. I would like to derive the value of my tag from a batch job parameter and add that.

If I can't do this, my plan is use a custom metric in the listener for the batch job. I assume that's a good place to put it.

Comment: `I would like to derive the value of my tag from a batch job parameter and add that.` Can you share a concrete example of that? The answer to how to do that depends on where you would add the tag (ie the code of adding the tag should have a handle to the step execution, or be defined in a step-scoped bean that has access to job parameters).

Comment: So, with a custom metric I can add the tag in a `JobExecutionListener` as it has access to the `JobExection` in `beforeJob` / `afterJob` which has the job params.

I'm wondering can I avoid the custom metric and instead add the tag to the built-in `spring.batch` job metric.

Comment: A code example:


`class MyJobExecutionListener{
afterJob(jobExecution: JobExecution) { String foobar = jobExecution.jobParameters.getString("foobar"); // get param
meterRegistry.timer(mytimer, "MyTag", foobar).duration(duration) // send custom metric
`

I want to remove that custom metric and use the built-in `spring.batch` one but with the tag.

Comment: This seems like a micrometer question rather than a spring batch question. I am not sure you can add a tag to an existing meter, but I think if you register a meter with the same name and additional tags it will replace the existing one if any. Have you tried that? BTW, Spring Batch uses the global registry of micometer, so if you can retrieve batch metrics in the listener and add tags to them then I think this is the way to address your initial requirement.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things that you can do:

1. Instead of using a `MeterFilter`, use an `ObservationFilter`, this let's you access to the batch context that should contain the data you want.
2. Batch's instrumentation should provide you a default `ObservationConvention` that you can override (there is also a global convention on the registry).

In both cases to have extra tags on your metrics, you need to add a `lowCardinalityKeyValue` to the Observation).